# python: using multiprocessing to geocode addresses

Tags: python, multiprocessing, geocoding

I have to geocode a large number of addresses so I am working on setting this up with multiprocessing in mind. I read [parallel geocoding](http://www.nearimprov.com/parallel-geocoding/) but this addressed using `geopy`. I will be using `geocoder` instead though.

```
import geocoder
import multiprocessing as mp

google_key = 'my_key'

addresses = ['tampa, florida', 'peroria, illinois', 'augusta, georgia',
             'hanover, new hampshire', 'burlington, vermont']

def geocode_worker(address):
    geocoder.google(address, key = google_key).latlng
    return address

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool(processes = (mp.cpu_count() - 1))
    result = pool.map(geocode_worker, addresses)
```

This returns the addresses as is where as I want the latitude and longitude back with a specific city. I need a little help getting everything working properly.

Comment: Of course it returns the address, because you have `return address` in your `geocode_worker` function.  May you want to instead return the `.latlng` attribute you reference in the previous line?

Comment: This is too silly read your code carefully you are supplying address to the function and returning the address

Comment: @larsks how would I return `.latlng`? I tried `address.latlng`

Comment: Just do `return geocoder.google(address, key = google_key).latlng`

Comment: @DeepSpace thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `geocode_worker` function should simply be the line
`return geocoder.google(address, key = google_key).latlng`